# Regex in Textwrangler - Remove String Between Two Characters

Tags: regex, string, textwrangler

I have a text file that has multiple weather statistics for popular cities, which includes not only the highs and lows for the current day, but also yesterday's weather, as shown below:

```
City/Town, State;Yesterday’s High Temp (F);Yesterday’s Low Temp (F);Today’s High Temp (F);Today’s Low Temp (F);Weather Condition;Wind Direction;Wind Speed (MPH);Humidity (%);Chance of Precip. (%);UV Index

Atlanta, GA;43;22;44;22;Partly sunny, chilly;NW;9;38%;7%;4
Atlantic City, NJ;45;24;37;9;A snow squall;WNW;22;36%;58%;3
Baltimore, MD;40;23;34;8;A snow squall, windy;NW;19;37%;57%;1
Bismarck, ND;-10;-29;-8;-15;Frigid;SSE;6;73%;58%;2
```

I'd like to be able to enter a regex command that will remove the first two numbers after the state, removing yesterday's high and low temperature, to have it look like this:

```
City/Town, State;Yesterday’s High Temp (F);Yesterday’s Low Temp (F);Today’s High Temp (F);Today’s Low Temp (F);Weather Condition;Wind Direction;Wind Speed (MPH);Humidity (%);Chance of Precip. (%);UV Index

Atlanta, GA;44;22;Partly sunny, chilly;NW;9;38%;7%;4
Atlantic City, NJ;37;9;A snow squall;WNW;22;36%;58%;3
Baltimore, MD;34;8;A snow squall, windy;NW;19;37%;57%;1
Bismarck, ND;-8;-15;Frigid;SSE;6;73%;58%;2
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match portion:

```
-?\d+;-?\d+;(-?\d+;-?\d+)
```

Substituion:

```
$1
```

Breaking it down:

```
Check for possible hyphen
-?
Check for number
\d+
Check for semicolon
;
Do the above again
-?\d+;
Start of capturing group
(
Do above check 2 times again
-?\d+;-?\d+
End of capturing group
)
```

`$1` means to replace it with the contents of the first capturing group.

You can also use this if you don't want to do any substitions:

```
-?\d+;-?\d+;(?=-?\d+;-?\d+)
```

It utilizes a lookahead to check if there are two more numbers in front of it.

Comment: I entered your Match portion command and it removed both yesterday and today's high and lows, so unfortunately it didn't work for me. I want to remove only yesterday's temperature and keep today's

Comment: It worked! This is fantastic, thank you so much!, I'll screencap this so I can learn from your explanation